# operand types are incompatible ("bool (*)()" and "bool")

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program in Visual Studio Community 2015 to play Tic-Tac-Toe. Sounds simple, not so much.
Anyway, I am using a function [bool playerCheck()] to make a switch for  the function that checks whether the space that the user chooses is already taken.

```
void checkInput()
{
    if (playerCheck == true)
```

Visual Studio gives the squiggly lines under the "==" and gives the message

operand types are incompatible ("bool (*)()" and "bool").

Not sure how the syntax should be for comparing function output to a constant.

Comment: Read a tutorial, *any* tutorial?

Comment: `playerCheck()` is how you would call `bool playerCheck() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: `if(playerCheck() == true)` or better `if(playerCheck())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playerCheck` is a function which needs to be called in order to get the boolean result, i.e.:

```
if (playerCheck() == true)
```

---

`bool (*)()` is a type for a *function which takes no arguments and returns a boolean.*

`playerCheck == true` is an attempt to compare the *function pointer* with a boolean value, which leads to the compilation error which speaks for itself.

`playerCheck() == true` is *calling* the function and comparing the result (of type boolean) with the boolean value.

---

Note that `if (x == true)` can be generally abbreviated to `if (x)`, so you could just write

```
if (playerCheck())
```

Comment: i wonder why the downvote - this is correct (apart from not pointing out that ==true is redundant)

Comment: @Pm100 Because answering such horrible questions (yes reading the first 10 lines of a tutorial is a great idea before asking on SO!) to get trivial rep encourages these questions which leads to a downward spiral.

Comment: u think answering badish questions is trying to get rep? Seems like people just trying to be helpful. I do it all the time. Sometimes tutorials for languages dont really cover some ultra fundamental things, having somebody point the answer out helps a lot. When I first learned fortran (a long time ago) they talked about the layout on a card , which cols for comments, etc. I was really puzzled by how limited it was till somebody pointed out that *you could have more than one card*

Comment: things that get me are people posting the text of an assignment , with no effort at all.